# Openfaces TabbedPane not working properly

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, glassfish, mojarra, openfaces

I'm having a problem with an Openface TabbedPane in a JSF application so I created a new application to test the TabbedPane. I have the following code in my page:

```
<h:form>
  <o:tabbedPane>
    <o:subPanel caption="Tab 1">
      <h:outputText value="Hello from tab 1"/>
    </o:subPanel>
    <o:subPanel caption="Tab 2">
      <h:outputText value="Hello from tab 2"/>
    </o:subPanel>
    <o:subPanel caption="Tab 3">
       <h:outputText value="Hello from tab 3"/>
    </o:subPanel>
    <o:subPanel caption="Tab 4">
       <h:outputText value="Hello from tab 4"/>
    </o:subPanel>
  </o:tabbedPane>
</h:form>
```

Initially tab 1 is shown. The next tab I click works (no matter which is the next) but no other tab when clicked works. For example when I click tab 2 I can see its contents but when I then click tab 3 I its contents are not shown and I still see previous tab's contents. I checked Mojarra's version on my Glassfish and it is 2.1.6. When I force the loading mode to be "client" everything is working but when I force it to be "server" I get the following error when I try to click a third tab:

> [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.sun.faces.application.view.StateHolderSaver

Answer (score 0):

There are some state-related issues with Mojarra 2.1.6, which are known to prevent OpenFaces from working correctly.

Officially, only Mojarra 2.0.3 is currently supported, but according to the preliminary testing Mojarra 2.1.8 appears to work as well (it still has to undergo additional testing before we declare compatibility with this version officially, but you can try see if it's acceptable for you).